# Converting a 10A supply into a 16A appliance

Tags: converter

Is it possible to insert a converter between regular 10A 240V mains supply that would be capable of running a tool rated at 16A, 3500W?

Obviously, the tool won't run to it's full capacity but could it work for a portion of its capacity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: No! blown fuse, or excess heat in the wire /connector could lead to fire.  (power goes as I^2...you do the math.)

Answer (score 2):

A 10 amp 240V supply can only deliver 2400 watts. If I assume the tool is rated for 240V and draws 16 amp, it would need a maximum of 3840 watts. The rating of 3500W may be because the tool does not have a power factor of 1.  In any case, a converter can only change one voltage into another (or change AC to DC); it cannot increase the wattage capacity of your main supply. Depending on the type of tool, you could damage it if the proper power is not applied.  There certainly is a good chance you will blow the main supply fuse or circuit breaker.